# Why PagedResourceAssembler clears my model links? [Spring HATEOAS]

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-hateoas, hateoas

I want to implement HATEOAS with Spring Boot. I achieve it and now I have another pagination problem. All I want to say is that pagination works like this:

```
{
  "links": [
    {
      "rel": "first",
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/posts?bookId=1&page=0&size=2"
    },
    {
      "rel": "self",
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/posts?bookId=1&page=0&size=2"
    },
    {
      "rel": "next",
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/posts?bookId=1&page=1&size=2"
    },
    {
      "rel": "last",
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/posts?bookId=1&page=1&size=2"
    }
  ],
  "content": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "bookId": 1,
      "title": "UpdatedPost1Title",
      "content": "UpdatedPost1Content",
      "created": "2021-01-18T20:42:39",
      "updated": "2021-01-18T23:16:48",
      "voteUp": 0,
      "voteDown": 0,
      "links": [
        
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "bookId": 1,
      "title": "title2",
      "content": "content2",
      "created": "2021-01-18T20:42:43",
      "updated": "2021-01-18T20:42:43",
      "voteUp": 0,
      "voteDown": 0,
      "links": [
        
      ]
    }
  ],
```

But as you can see all my internal "links" are empty. I ran debugger and the line which cause this weird behaviour is:

```
PagedModel<EntityModel<PostDto>> page = pagedResourcesAssembler.toModel(postPage);
```

from this method:

```
@GetMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public ResponseEntity<PagedModel<EntityModel<PostDto>>> getPosts(@RequestParam(required = false) Long bookId,
                                                        @PageableDefault(size = DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE) Pageable pageable) {
        Optional<Long> bookParam = Optional.ofNullable(bookId);

        Page<PostDto> postPage = bookParam.map(aLong -> postService.getByBookId(aLong, pageable).map(assembler::toModel))
                .orElseGet(() -> postService.getAllPosts(pageable).map(assembler::toModel));

        PagedModel<EntityModel<PostDto>> page = pagedResourcesAssembler.toModel(postPage); //this line

        return new ResponseEntity<>(page, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Before this line Page keeps information about internal links which I added before (assembler::toModel).

What should I do to prevent my model get cleared by pagedResourcesAssembler? (it's org.springframework.data.web.PagedResourcesAssembler).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

And yey I found an answer here: https://howtodoinjava.com/spring5/hateoas/pagination-links/. It should looks like this:

```
@GetMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public ResponseEntity<PagedModel<PostDto>> getPosts(@RequestParam(required = false) Long bookId,
                                                        @PageableDefault(size = DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE) Pageable pageable) {
        Optional<Long> bookParam = Optional.ofNullable(bookId);

        Page<Post> postPage = bookParam.map(aLong -> postService.getByBookId(aLong, pageable))
                .orElseGet(() -> postService.getAllPosts(pageable));

        PagedModel<PostDto> page = pagedResourcesAssembler.toModel(postPage, assembler);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(page, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

as you can see PagedResourcesAssembler should be of entity type, not of model type. Also I remove mapping before creating PagedModel and use .toModel(Page, RepresentationModelAssembler) method.